# Javascript Regex to remove any spaces, special characters and numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

At the moment I have the following `$scope.user.username.replace(/[\s]/g, '');`

This removes and special characters and spaces, I need to add in the ability to prevent numbers and special characters too but I can't quite grasp how Regex works.

Would someone be able to help me out?

Comment: Actually your regex remove only white spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the characters you want to remove in the character class:

```
replace(/[\s.;,?%0-9]/, '')
```

Answer (score 3):

You should just be able to use `not` in the matching group and remove everything that isn't a letter:

```
/[^a-zA-Z]/g
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/n1ew8099/1/)